# Please review my design for a solenoid controller

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design

I have been designing and testing a circuit for controlling multiple solenoids over a CAN bus. After a lot of reading and trying I have come to this design. but this is my first time designing such a complex PCB (I have done simpler ones before).

All the parts are already tested on a breadboard and this worked fine. The MOSFETs will drive solenoids with a peak current of 3 A. At max they will switch each second. MOSFETs are chosen because of space limitations and vibrations at the mounting location. At a given time no more then 3 solenoids will be on.

I would like to hear what you guys think I did wrong or can do better, circuit and layout wise.

Thanks already!

Trace widths:
0.25 mm signals;
0.5 mm power and some signals;
2 and 4 mm power to MOSFETs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can do a lot of minimizing tracks on the blue side (U15 and U4) because they disrupt the ground plane.

Comment: You probably should use smaller resistors (1k or less) in series with the MOSFET gates. The 3.3k and 10k will provide only about 3.7V for the gates with 5V logic. This may or may not be enough to fully turn on.

Comment: Personal pet peeve that I share with many EEs:  Ground symbols should always point down.

Comment: Count me out on that one. I don't really care which way they point because they are a single point node naming mechanism and are hardly mistaken for anything else other than what they are.

Comment: Fair enough @Andyaka, but some of us are running on limited cognitive space, so the smoother my mind can flow over the diagram, the better.

Comment: 1) Did you mean "HEIGHT_SENSOR_1"?  Typos in signal names can look awful on a nice PCB.  2) My pet peeves are absence of title block and cramped looking diagrams which hide structure and regularity.

Comment: perhaps use a `J` designator for connectors ... `U` usually refers to ICs

Comment: 1N4001GP or similar would be better than 1N4148 ...

Comment: Looks like someone used the autorouter. Don’t use the autorouter. With the schematic you can use multiple sheets so you can make the drawing more consistent and readable. Humans have trouble finding errors in random drawings. Try to have your ics point the same way on the pcb. Again, having things regular makes it easier for humans to spot an error.

Comment: I understand now that labels look nice, but wires are easier to understand. But i didn't use auto router, is something wrong this way?

Comment: On the PCB, make sure you have the screw terminals facing the direction you intend.  You have them lined up along the edges, but it looks like the openings for the external wires are pointed away from the edges.  You might also want to indicate polarity of the connectors on the silkscreen.  DC solenoids don't care about the polarity, but if it has an indicator LED, the user might care.

Comment: No single answer can cover all the mistakes and improvements will be somewhat opinion based anyway, so no answer will be more correct than others. Also you more likely want feedback on if the circuit in the schematics will work, instead of how the schematics looks, or both?

Comment: I am looking for feedback from either one, just trying to become a better engineer. Haven't done much of PCB desing yet, and from my experience so far everyone has his/her own style of circuit design so every answer will be different and none perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Great Schematic, making worth our time to check it out.The design is good, however you are driving the gates of the MOSFETs with ~3.7V. You should place the Pull down resistors R1 R2... between ground where they are and the Pin of the 74HC595, this will eliminate the voltage divider and drive the MOSFETs further in to enhancement causing them to run cooler. I cannot fully check as I do not know what MOSFETs you are using. That change will still keep them off until the processor gets control. the 1N4148 are nice and small,to small for your 12V 3A solenoid, the surge capacity of the Diode can be exceeded by a large margin. Overall Great Job!

Great Link tinjvr, Thanks that will help a lot of people!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did some reasearch and eliminated the voltage divider, this links has a nice example (https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/mosfet-gate-resistor/). I also changed the diodes to bigger ones (MBRS360T3G) that can handle 3 A.

Comment: @tijnvr As far as schematics go, I wouldn't call it atrocious, but it sure isn't pretty. Look at schematics for older test equipment from HP, Tektronix, etc. that had them included in the service manual. A schematic for something this simple should *flow* every signal using lines. It's supposed to **graphically** represent connections and data/signal flow. The one shown in the question is more like a netlist with some graphical symbols thrown in. It's not a schematic in the sense of an engineering drawing (which it should be). It hardly conveys function, which it should - at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not much, you have a continuous ground plane which will help with EMI. Using solid planes or bigger traces around the DC DC converter would help with parasitics. Another thing that could be better is the traces to the solenoids, which could be a bit bigger. Other than that looks good.

Answer (score 1):

- If the solenoid is 3A, then the flyback diodes need to handle the 3A surges and the 1N4148 can't handle it.
- The diodes on sensors to 12V can't protect the Arduino from damage as they allow up to 12V.
- Any amount of solenoids, maybe all, may be turned on when circuit powers up. The shift register is permanently enabled and it will power up in a random state, as the reset is not used.
- Before the Arduino starts running code and configures the IO pins, they float. The shift registers may get invalid data and load instructions from noise on floating bus.
- The resistors on FET gate are quite large in resistance so the FET is driven slowly. The FET may spend too much time transitioning between on and off states, and so when it is halfway on, it has to dissipate a lot of power. You need to check if that is OK or if you need to change anything.
- CAN bus has no ground pin. The bus may work without a ground reference, but it might not. It is not clear if the ground is coming from the same system which provides the CAN bus, so they might already share the ground reference.
- CAN bus is directly connected between chip and connector. There is no noise filtering or protection of any kind. It may work just fine. You also are not using the termination features the CAN PHY chip provides, i.e. the Vref pin. Even if you don't use the 120 ohm resistor, in some cases you may want weaker termination for intermediate devices. And sometimes the 120 ohm resistor is split into two 60 ohm resistors and a common mode noise suppression cap to ground is added.
- The PCB layout for the regulator is likely against what regulator data sheet suggests. You really need to organize the wiring and components so it makes sense in the context of high frequency, high current pulses and fast voltage transitions.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of your LM2576 looks like it's going to introduce a lot of headaches.  You want to minimize switching loop area as much as possible; by moving around L2, C1, and D2, I think you can slim it down quite a bit.  Also, I would confirm that the current you are planning on pulling off of the 5V rail supports not heatsinking the LM2576 at all.

Comment: I can only emphasize this - do everything you can to shorten these traces, also care for their width (dimension them for the peak switching currents, not the average supply current drawn!). Minimize the the enclosed area of the switching loop as @vir mentioned. Move components closer together and rotate them only focused on this. Don't care for elegance!
Give the capacitors more than just one small via to the ground plane. I'd prefer to put a top layer ground polygon around the capacitor pads with at least three thermals and then stitch this polygon to the ground layer with a number of vias.

Answer (score 0):

The \$\overline{SRCLR}\$ pin on the SN74HC595N shift registers is connected to VCC. This means there is no explicit reset of the shift registers at power-up, and so some of the outputs might turn on at power on, until the software in the Arduino Nano has started running and initialised the shift registers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to introduce some hardening of the power input against polarity error, ESD, Noise from the 12V supply and so on.
=> some sort of ferrite bead or filter, TVS and fuse/current limiter are not the worst idea.

Comment: That is a good idea. I am going to add a fuse for sure. Correct me if i am wrong but is ESD protection with a diode not the same as overvoltage protection? Or are these completely different?

Comment: A TVS provides overvoltage protection - may it be transient, due to electrostatic discharge, burst pulses or continous. Take a closer look at the datasheet, they state the typical DC operating range and also the maximum current. You need to limit the current by other means such as a fuse, serial resistor, ohmic resistance of a ferrite beads etc. I'd prefer unidirectional for DC supply operation, and often combine it with polarity protection if the consumed current is relatively small.

Comment: Just imagine a decent 500V spike of a few ms duration on the digital input and look how this would get clamped to the 12V supply and how that would modify the 12V supply.